# WooCommerce custom notification issue with $email variable argument

Tags: php, wordpress, object, woocommerce, email-notifications

I have 2 custom email mailers setup as `wc_shipped_order` & `wc_received_order` and it works great. I have the trigger set so when the status of an order is changed to "shipped" it triggers the shipped order email mailer.

I'm trying to add a Tracking shipping code through another custom plugin via the action hook `woocommerce_email_before_order_table` with the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'tracking_number_email', 10, 4 );
function tracking_number_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if( 'wc_shipped_order_email' == $email->id ){
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Australia Post Tracking Number').': </strong>' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'tracking_number', true ) . '</p>';
    }
}
```

However when I try and add an if statement to check if the mailer was `wc_shipped_order`, I get an error. The actual echo part works, but the **IF** statement is failing and throwing out this error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in /var/www/wp-content/plugins/my-custom-functions/inc/php/functional.php(103) : eval()'d code on line 239
```

It has no idea what `$email->id` is and I've tried dumping that variables for `$email` but theres nothing there.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

In WooCommerce `$email` variable argument is expected to be an object where you can get some properties *(like the `id` in your code)*. The error thrown tells that it's not an object, so it's not possible get any property from it *(and so not the `id` property)*.

To avoid this problem, you could use PHP conditional function `is_object()` like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'tracking_number_email', 10, 4 );
function tracking_number_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if( is_object($email) && 'wc_shipped_order_email' == $email->id ){
        $tracking_number = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'tracking_number', true );

        if ( ! empty($tracking_number) ) {
            echo '<p><strong>'.__('Australia Post Tracking Number').': </strong>' . $tracking_number . '</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

It should works now without error.

Now this problem can be related to a plugin, your theme or some other custom code made by you. With the provided information nobody can guess why this happen.